# Why does the words shifts to next line while using flutter on VSCode?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I don't know why, whenever I write a function or its parameters in VSCode while using flutter, it automatically shifts to the next line even when not required.
Currently, **The indent in vs code is settings to 180.**

example screenshot

[image]